# Plot multiple lines with matplotlib, using only 3 lists/arrays

Tags: matplotlib, lines

I would like to plot say 10 lines in 3D in matplotlib, but without having to use ax.plot(x,y,z) 10 times.
This is the ridiculous code I've come up with b/c I can't envision how the zip and arrays actually work together.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = np.array([0.,3.])
y = np.array([0.,0.])
z = np.array([0.,0.])

u = np.array([0.,3.])
v = np.array([.5,.5])
w = np.array([0.,0.])

a = np.array([0.,3.])
b = np.array([1.,1.])
c = np.array([0.,0.])

e = np.array([0.,3.])
d = np.array([1.5,1.5])
f = np.array([0.,0.])

r = np.array([0.,3.])
s = np.array([2.,2.])
t = np.array([0.,0.])

ax.set_xlabel("x axis")
ax.set_ylabel("y axis")
ax.set_zlabel("z axis")


ax.plot(x,y,z)
ax.plot(a,b,c)
ax.plot(r,s,t)
ax.plot(u,v,w)
ax.plot(e,d,f)


plt.show()
```

I'm guessing I'll use zip and/or a for loop.
Thanks, and here's the figure.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store all your data points in a large data array. This way you can loop over the array and do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# initialize array with size number of lines
data = np.full((2,3), None) 

# fill data array with data points [x,y,z]
data[0] = [[0,3],[0,0],[0,0]]
data[1] = [[0,3],[0.5,0.5],[0,0]]
# etc...

# loop over data array and plot lines
for line in data:
    ax.plot(line[0],line[1],line[2])

plt.show()
```

There are many different ways on how to store your data, you could also skip the initialization step by just creating the array in one take:

```
data = np.array([[[0,3],[0,0],[0,0]],
                 [[0,3],[0.5,0.5],[0,0]],
                 [[0,3],[0.5,0.5],[0,0]],
                 [...] ])
```

Or use numpy functions like [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy-concatenate) to add new lines to the data array.